# ValidationError message doesn't appear in my own form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I created a custom registration form:

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta():
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'mobile', 'address']

    def clean_mobile(self):
        mobile = self.cleaned_data['mobile']
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(mobile=mobile).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Mobile already exists')
        return mobile

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.mobile = self.cleaned_data['mobile']
        user.address = self.cleaned_data['address']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

And in my template, I don't write just `{{form}}', instead I use my bootstrap template for registration. It looks like:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'register' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="username1" >Ім'я користувача <sup>*</sup></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="username1" placeholder="Нік" name="username">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="password_1" >Пароль <sup>*</sup></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" id="password_1" placeholder="Введіть пароль" name="password1">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="password_2" >Повторіть пароль <sup>*</sup></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" id="password_2" placeholder="Повторіть пароль" name="password2">
                </div>
            </div>
```

But when `clean_mobile` method is called and raise `ValidationError`, no errors aren't showed. How to solve this issue? Or maybe I can use in template `{{form}}` but I need to use bootstrap css?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `{{ form.mobile.errors }}` to display errors for your `mobile` field.

See the [working with form templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates) docs for more information.

You might want to investigate [django crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which makes it easy to render bootstrap forms.